# ANDROID EditText onclicklistener?

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have here two EditTexts' (username and password) and I want it to look like this on the start of the application:

[image]

But after the user should click the EditTexts' i want it to automatically delete the "username"(and "password"), like this:

[image]

how should i do that trick? can anyone help me, please? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the property `android:hint`

```
<EditText
    android:hint="Username">
</EditText>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is something easier: use the [hint](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3ahint)-property, it does exactly what you want.
It's only shown when the EditText ist empty.

Answer (score 0):

Use the android:hint tag in the xml

E.g.,

```
        <EditText  
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:hint="username"
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `android:hint="UserName"` in the xml file.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/username"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:hint="Enter Text to Send"
android:inputType="text" 
android:text="" />
```

and also use `android:password="true"` in the password `EditText`